# Kendo DatePickerFor Windows 10 on Edge is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker

I use kendo UI in my project and since the new browser Edge was released on windows 10 something strange has happened.
I initialize the value for a datepicker like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m).Value(DateTime.Now.Date))
```

This code is working fine in IE, Chrome, Firefox and all the others browsers but not on Edge. On Edge is not setting the value with my parameter. If I set the value from javascript all it's fine.

Does anybody knows what could cause this behavior ?

Thanks!

Comment: It's working fine in my project. Can you show your code and if you have any errors in console?

Comment: I don't have any errors in console. Have you tried on Microsoft Edge ?

Comment: Yes, below is my code

Comment: Might help to see the HTML that the helper is rendering.

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.telerik.com/forums/datepicker-broken-in-microsoft-edge#5z5jT-yDX0eLkSuvlLC5AQ][1]

It seems that it is a problem. Let's hope that we will receive an update to Kendo UI or maybe Microsoft will resolve this problem on Edge.

Comment: do they have release a fix yet?

Comment: I updated to the latest version of kendo ui and everything work's fine. I should mention that I updated two weeks ago

Answer (score -1):

This is my code and he working fine:

```
<input id="datePicker" data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: Project.Date"
style="width: 100%" required="required" data-val-required="your_custom_text"
data-val-date="your_custom_text" data-val="true">   


 <script>
    var dateFormat =  'MM/dd/yyyy';
    var datePicker = $("#datePicker");
    datePicker.kendoDatePicker({
                            format: dateFormat,
                            parseFormats: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
                            culture: '@UICulture'
                        });
    datePicker.attr("readonly", "readonly");
    datePicker.on('click', function () {
                            datePicker.data("kendoDatePicker").open();
                        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes, If I do like you, in script area it's working but if I try to use the razor sintax and set the value from razor it's not working. The value will be null but only on Microsoft Edge, on all the other browsers is working fine.

Comment: Its broken from Razor mate